# Is the massless Klein Gordon action conformally invariant?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime

The kinetic term for a real scalar field is the usual $\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi$. I've read that when lifting to a curved background, one often modifies the kinetic term (non-minimal coupling) to preserve conformal invariance. **My issue**: I don't see how the action is conformally invariant even in flat space.

If I do a conformal transformation of the minkowski metric: $g_{\mu\nu}(x)=\Omega^2(x)\eta_{\mu\nu}(x)$, or $\eta_{\mu\nu}(x)=\Omega^{-2}g_{\mu\nu}(x)$, I interpret this as rescaling the geometry but not the coordinate system (x isn't changing). Then, in flat space,
$S_{kinetic} = \int d^4x\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi =\int d^4x \eta^{\mu\alpha}\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\alpha\phi=\int d^4x\Omega^{2}g'^{\mu\alpha}\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\alpha\phi$
so the action was not left invariant.

Here I implicitly make several assumptions:

1. Conformal invariance should be preserved for both the equations of motion AND the action.
2. There is no $\sqrt{-g}$ to transform in flat space.
3. $\partial_\mu$ doesn't transform but $\partial^\mu=\eta^{\mu\alpha}\partial_\alpha$ does.
4. The field $\phi(x)$ doesn't change because x doesn't change.

I suspect some of these assumptions must be wrong. Obviously the flat space equation of motion for a massless field $\partial_\mu\partial^\mu\phi=0$ is left invariant for $\Omega^2(x)\neq0$, but shouldn't the action as well? If I relax assumption 2 and let $\eta=\text{det}|\eta_{\mu\nu}|$, then we have $\sqrt{-g}=\Omega^4\sqrt{-\eta}$, so even including that gives

$S_{kinetic}=\int d^4x \Omega^{-2}g'^{\mu\alpha}\partial_\mu\phi\partial_\alpha\phi$

which still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: How are you changing $g$ without changing $x$?

Comment: assumption 2 is wrong when you deal with conformal transformation since the measure will also rescale. But if your conformal factor is constant it will be an overall factor by which you can divide the action and you will return to the same massless scalar.

Comment: @jacob1729 I figured the geometry is independent from the coordinate system I use to describe it. Why can't I use the same coordinates to parameterize two different metrics? Also $x$ is a dummy variable being integrated over. How do I apply a transformation to a variable the action knows nothing about?

Comment: @Kosm But $\Omega= \Omega(x)$ in general. I can't just factor it out of the action.

Comment: @user143854 yes you cannot factor out x-dependent $\Omega$, what is the problem with that? You wrote yourself "when lifting to curved background, one often modifies the kinetic term".

Comment: @Kosm My apologies, I misread your comment as "but your conformal factor is constant". I'm just asking how is the flat space kinetic contribution to the action conformally invariant when there seems to be conformal factors left over whether or not I include the transformation of $\sqrt{-g}$.

Comment: @user143854 in flat space (not to confuse with conformally flat) Omega is constant and can be ignored as an overall factor